# iOS Xcode project file sharing for multiple developers

Tags: ios, xcode

What is the best practice for multiple developers working on the same iOS project? Is there a way to avoid having to reset the code signing build settings (while keeping the rest shared) when multiple developers are working on the same Xcode project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the code signing identity to `iPhone Developer (Automatic selection)` instead of `iPhone Developer: Joe McDoe`, then it will automatically find an appropriate signing identity in the local keychain, and it should work fine for each developer on your team.